# What is the area bounded by the two graphs $y =\sin x$ and $y =\sin x\cos2x$? $(0\le x\le\pi)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> What is the area bounded by the two graphs $y =\sin x$ and $y =\sin x\cos2x$? $(0\le x\le\pi)$

**My approach**

$$\int^\pi_0\sin x -\sin x \cos2x \ dx$$
$$\int^\pi_0\sin x (1-\cos2x) \ dx$$

As $\cos2x = \cos(x+x)$

$\cos2x =\cos x \cos x -\sin x \sin x =\cos^2x-\sin^2x$

And as $\sin^2x + \cos^2x=1,$

$$\int^\pi_0\sin x (1-\cos2x) \ dx = \int^\pi_0\sin x \left(\sin^2x + \cos^2x-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)\right) \ dx$$

$$=\int^\pi_0\sin x (2\sin^2x) = \int^\pi_02\sin^3x \ dx$$

Doing the integration gives me

$$\left[\frac{\sin^4x}{2\cos x}\right]^\pi_0$$
which is 0. Using technology to verify this answer, it was $\frac{8}{3}$ instead of 0. A calculator suggests my approach is valid, but there is clearly something wrong in my calculation.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you arrived to
$$=\int^\pi_0\sin x (2\sin^2x) dx$$
you do the following
$$\int_0^{\pi } 2 \sin (x) \left(1-\cos ^2(x)\right) \, dx$$
and then substitute $\cos(x)=u\rightarrow -\sin(x)\,dx=du$
The integral becomes
$$\int_1^{-1} -2 \left(1-u^2\right) \, du=\left. 2 \left(\frac{u^3}{3}-u\right)\right|_1^{-1}=\frac{8}{3}$$

Answer (score -1):

Cause your last integral is incorrect, $$ \int^\pi_02\sin^3x \ dx = \left[\frac{1}{12} (\cos(3 x) - 9\cos(x))\right]_0^{\pi}  \ne \left[\frac{\sin^4x}{2\cos x}\right]^\pi_0$$

Comment: The asker already understands that at some point in his/her work, they made a mistake.  You only tell the OP.  Yes, you did, the integration is incorrect. (Why? And how did you get the (what you claim is correct) evaluation of the integral? Why should any user believe you?)  Hardly a useful answer.